# Is this back-end task cpu intensive for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a android-app and I am not sure whether to use node.js or php as back-end.

> I have this task, where user provides some query parameters(zip code), and I perform some db query, If I find some result, I return it, else I check on various levels like zip, city, metro, state etc. until I find some non zero results.

Is  this task too cpu intensive for node.js? Will checking for various level of queries as shown above slow down the single thread of node.js?

What is the criterion to decide what task is cpu intensive and what is not?

Comment: Its the query you need to worry about. Properly configured platforms such as php or node are almost competent for such simpler tasks.

Comment: This sounds entirely IO based.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't worry about php or node JS. They are both blithingly fast for the relative simple operation you are talking about and their overhead is minimal. Your bottleneck is more likely the sql queries. And that is more or less platform independant.

Instead of doing multiple queries to get the results you want, try to come up with a query that will do it in one go. That way the SQL optimizer can do it's job and keep overhead to a minimum and return results immedeately.

To test your cpu performance, the easiest way is to time your code. Longer time usually equals more cpu intensive. Get the micro/nanoseconds before your application does its thing and get them after your application is done, substract and you know how long your application took to execute.
You can also time your queries, use the SQL optimising tools to improve your queries, make them more efficient.

Comment: I agree, but I am learning node.js and was not sure if this kind of operation is appropriate for node, where I have to perform multiple if conditions check before returning the data. Can I combination of the two.. php and node.js? node.js for straight-forward back-end tasks and php for relatively complex task as above?

Comment: I would not per se go with php for the comlex tasks. And as I've stated, your bottle neck is that you do multiple queries. that adds delay, cpu overhead. Try to come up with a way to do your code in sql. You can use sql functions. For example in [mysql](http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/create-function-examples.html) it's easy to create a function for a complex task, but it will run in the scope of one performance check by the query optimiser

Answer (score 0):

the db response callback will be called only when db returns the data, so in the mean time node's thread should be free to do other things (serving other requests)

For the sake of simplicity I would stick to php if you know it. Node can be mind bending

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if you should use node.js or php as a solution to your problem, but are using "cpu intensive" as a criterium. I don't think this criterium will help you very much in choosing between the two, at least in this case. Even if you really wanted to say "latency", there will be no (user-)appreciable difference.

See, **your query is so simple that cpu usage most likely won't be an issue**. The reason is that most of the cpu time will be lost in performing the query, which is essentially done by the database rather than php or nodejs itself. You're best off spending your time writing a performant query (which is easy enough)

Contrary to what others say, and sorry for this slightly purist remark: **you should not test cpu intensivity by testing the time before and after you handle things**, not in nodejs or php. There are two (main) reasons for this:

- by doing this, you would also be measuring the latency involved in retrieving the data (which is NOT the job of php or node.js but rather that of the database)
- you don't know what 'else' php and node.js is doing during the time of measurement. For example, there may be other requests coming in that are being handled (ie concurrency). This will be especially apparent in node.js where you will probably fire off the query asynchronously.

Regardless, given the type of query involved and given THIS case, the choice between php or node.js shouldn't be based on "cpu intensivity". Try considering different criteria such as "how fast can I develop this", in which case I would probably opt for php, *in this very simple case*. (Note: I'm a big proponent of node.js, so this is hard for me to say)